# Quote about trying before seeing

Tags: reference-request, education

Which book says, probably in its preface, that when you see a theorem in a math book, you should make a serious attempt to prove it before looking at the book’s proof? Thanks.

I know a similar quote that says when you are solving an exercise, you should never look at the solution, because solving a difficult problem brings you the greatest satisfaction.

Also, Bellman said, if you can’t solve a problem, you should treat it like a research problem.

Comment: I believe that many authors, teachers and students share this point of view. I would be surprised if this could be attributed to a single person. As far as exercises, these are meant to test our knowledge of the material so I would check the solution if I had it.

Comment: @JohnDouma I remember seeing this quote in a book, but I have forgotten which. If there are multiple, any one in book form will do. Also, of course you can check the answer after solving a problem; but before arriving at your own solution, you should try by yourself. Of course I didn’t follow this advice by asking here.

Comment: This reminds of a famous anecdote: George Dantzig once arrived late in a class, saw two problems the professor had written on the board (which were actually some of the most famous open problems in statistics at that time), thought they were homework problems... and solved them.

Comment: I am not sure about a specific book but it does seem to be a common recommendation. Even if you have a proof for a theorem, it is good to look at the author's proof. You may believe you have found a simpler proof and wonder why the author's is more complicated. At times you will be right but at other times you may have overlooked a detail.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni I have also heard that anecdote said of Hawking and John Conway.

Comment: @JohnDouma Well, at least it is on Wikipedia's page of George Dantzig.

Comment: @ZiruiWang It somewhat also depends upon the book. Some books divide theorems in small steps, using lemmas, so each step is easier to demonstrate; some don't, so the difficulty is higher. Some books also regularly explain the "big picture" and describe the road ahead, so it is easier for the student to find proofs.

Comment: @JohnDouma I agree with the missing details part; math is rigorous and the devil is in the details, as the saying goes.

Answer (score 0):

Jeffrey Stopple wrote on page xiii of *A Primer of Analytic Number Theory*:

> Most [exercises] have solutions in the back, but you should at least make a serious attempt before reading the solution.